# v-autocomplete only shows filtered option after clicking clear button

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetify-1

I have a v-autocomplete (vuetify version 1) which shows the first 20 options then when the user scrolls further, the options will increment by 20 by querying from the database.

Each option's text is like this: `"<name> (<id>)"`

What I have noticed is that when I search (search input) for an option by its ID for example '21', if id '21' where in the first 20 options while id '121' yes yet to be queried from the database, the v-autocomplete will only show id 121 option.

If I click the clearable button, suddenly both option (id '21', and '121') will be shown. This is quite unusual especially that when i first search '21' the item array contains both id '21' and '121' options despite only display the '121' option.

This bug only occurs for searching by id though. If i search by name then all is well.

.vue:

```
           <v-autocomplete
             class="ml-4" 
             box 
             :items="options" 
             :loading="optionsFetching" 
             item-text="name" 
             item-value="id" 
             chips 
             deletable-chips
             single-line 
             multiple 
             clearable 
             return-object 
             :search-input.sync="searchText" 
             v-model="searched"
             @click="fetchDropdownDom()"
              >
                <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                  <v-chip
                    :selected="data.selected"
                    close
                    class="chip--select-multi"
                    @input="removeSelectedItem(data.item)"                  
                  >
                    {{ data.item.name }}({{ data.item.id }})
                  </v-chip>
                </template>
                <template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item }">
                  <v-list-tile-content >
                    <v-list-tile-title>{{item.name}} ({{item.id}})</v-list-tile-title>
                  </v-list-tile-content>
                </template>
            </v-autocomplete>
....

  watch:{
    searched:{ //vuex getter
      handler(newVal){
        if(newVal.length===0){
          this.setSearched([])//vuex mutation
       }
      }
    },

      searchText: _debounce(async function (searchText) {
      let queryString = typeof searchText === 'string' ? searchText : '';
      let hasExisted = this.options.find(({ id, name }) => {
        return name.toLowerCase() === queryString.toLowerCase();
      });
      
      if (!hasExisted) {
        await this.getOptions(searchText);
      };
    }, 1000),
}
```

vuex store:

```
async getOptions({ commit, getters, rootGetters }, searchText = '') {
      try {
        commit('optionsFetching', true);
        let { searched, options, offset } = getters;

        let { data: nameOptions } = await fetch({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'api/mgmt/name_option',
          params: {
            offset,
            searchText,
          }
        });

        if (nameOptions.length === 0) {
          return;
        } else {
          let optionsQueried = offset
            ? Object.assign([], options).concat(nameOptions.filter(each => !options.map(({ id }) => id).includes(each.id)))
            : nameOptions;
            commit('options', [
              ...searched,
              ...optionsQueried.filter(({id}) => {return !searched.includes(id);})
            ]);
          }
        commit('optionsFetching', false);
      } catch (error) {
        log(error);
        commit('optionsFetching', false);
      }
    },
```

Comment: Do you have a CodeSandbox or jsFiddle?